# Discord.py discord.Embed.from_dict not creating an embed properly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
with open("C:/Users/leola/Desktop/Leo/Coding/Python/DISCORD_BOT/help_alt.json", 'r') as help_file:
        help_commands = json.load(help_file)
    # help_commands["embed"]["author"]["name"] = bot.user.display_name
    # help_commands["embed"]["footer"]["text"] = f'{curr_page}/{num_pages}'
    print(help_commands)
    help_embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(help_commands)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=help_embed)
```

[My json](https://pastebin.com/n5zGKHMS)

I asked someone on discord for help and they said the json worked for them and they could get an embed from this, for some reason it's broken for me and gives me a `Can't send empty message` error code, the dict is fine when I print it out

Comment: I found a workaround with just a json with the names and values of fields as keys and value in a dict and just running it through a for loop, still not happy about having to do that though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me:

```py
@bot.command()
async def gojson(ctx):
    with open('example.json', 'r') as help_file:
        help_commands = json.load(help_file)
        help_embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(help_commands)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=help_embed)
```

[image]

Send the full error.

Comment: Umm, so I pasted my code again so I could give you the error because I found a workaround, got the json again and now it magically works, just... what?