# Parsing json data for embed in discord using discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I am trying to take json from a site called http://discohook.org

I would then like to be able to put the json it generates into a discord command for the bot to then post as an embed message.

This is what I have as my code:

```py
payload = message.content.strip("$embed ")
embed = Embed.from_dict(json.loads(payload))
await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

The json looks like this:

```json
{
  "content": null,
  "embeds": [
    {
      "title": "Testy Test",
      "description": "Hello World!",
      "color": 16711680,
      "footer": {
        "text": "I hope this works"
      },
      "timestamp": "2021-12-09T11:36:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I use the command with the above json (or any other seemingly-valid json for that matter), I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dev\London-RP\lrp-bot\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Dev\London-RP\lrp-bot\_Project\lrp-bot\main.py", line 116, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
  File "D:\Dev\London-RP\lrp-bot\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\dpy_overrides.py", line 323, in send_override
    return await send(channel, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Dev\London-RP\lrp-bot\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\dpy_overrides.py", line 300, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(
  File "D:\Dev\London-RP\lrp-bot\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message
```

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!
(Edit: Included full error)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: did you check what you get in variables? Maybe you really have empty variables. OR maybe it needs something else to send it. You have only `footer text` but not `message text`

Comment: similar [Discord.py discord.Embed.from_dict not creating an embed properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62390411/discord-py-discord-embed-from-dict-not-creating-an-embed-properly) but example JSON has `fields` with `name`, `value`. Maybe you also need it. OR maybe you need other elements - like `image` or `video`

Comment: @furas I've edited to include full error, apologies for not including it the first time.

Answer (score 2):

[`from_dict()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.from_dict) & [`to_dict()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.to_dict) methods work on/with Embed objects. So, the json message needs to be trimmed down to a single embed message like below else the function `discord.Embed.from_dict()` cannot parse it to appropriate fields (find documentation of [supported fields here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object)) causing the above empty message error.

**Note:** Added timezone in the timestamp because of time parsing issue in `discord/utils.py", line 110, in parse_time`.

Please find the full sample code which I used to test below,

```
import discord
import json

bot = discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})')
    print('------')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    response = '''
        {
          "title": "Testy Test",
          "description": "Hello World!",
          "color": 16711680,
          "footer": {
            "text": "I hope this works"
          },
          "timestamp": "2021-12-09T11:36:00.000+00:00"
        }
    '''
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.reply('Hello!', mention_author=True)

    if message.content.startswith('$embed'):
        payload = message.content.strip("$embed ")
        embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(json.loads(response))
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

bot.run('token')
```

**Output:**

[image]